# Swift Remove Item plist

Tags: swift, ios8

in my progect i add a item on plist in this mode

```
//Get path of Documents directory
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory:AnyObject = paths[0]
var path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("samplePlist.plist")
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var fileExists:Bool = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)
var data : NSMutableDictionary?
//Check if plist file exists at path specified
if fileExists == false {
//File does not exists
data = NSMutableDictionary () //Create data dictionary for storing in plist
} else  {
//File exists – retrieve data from plist inside data dictionary
data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
data?.setValue("hi", forKey: "NameButton")
```

my plist is this

```
<dict>
<key>NameButton</key>
<string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and if i want remove NameButton from my plist ?

Comment: So your question is how to remove a value from NSMutableDictionary ?

Comment: You can't modify a plist included with the main bundle.  You can modify `data`, but this will not persist.